# Find the nearest point to another point

Tags: java, point

I have 4 points, each of them indicates the middle of sides of rectangle.The 5th(main) point can be placed anywhere. How can I find the nearest of those 4 points to the main point, what is code implementation?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate distance between two points?

Comment: use pythagoras to find the distance between the clicked point and the fixed points

Comment: More suited for http://math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Just make an http request to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+between+%285%2C5%29+and+%288%2C7%29 and parse the results. Simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calculate the difference between the x- and y- coordinates of each point relative to yours. Then use pythagorus theorum to determine the actual distance from your point.

Comment: I was just typing this. You beat me to it.

Comment: Sorry but I cant understand how should I use pythagorus theorum to determine the actual distance from my point, would you please write more detailed answer

Comment: If your point has coordinates (x,y) and another point is at (p,q) then the vertical distance between them is y-q (i.e y minus q) and the horizontal distance is x-p. These lengths are the shorter two sides of a right-angled triangle (draw it on a piece of paper - it's more obvious), so the hypoteneuse is the distance between the two points. In other words...     sqrt( (x-p)^2 + (y-q)^2 )